# nth-child, assign styles to every element that is a multiple of 4

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a 4 column grid based layout and I want to apply CSS3 animations in a similar way to this;

```
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 1s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 2s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 3s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 4s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 1s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 2s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 3s -->
<div class="block"></div><!-- animation-duration: 4s -->
```

So basically, items in the first column have an animation duration of 1s, items in the second column have a 2s animation duration, etc. etc.

How can I achieve this with nth-child?

Comment: use __:nth-child(4n)__

Comment: What have you tried ? once you know about nth-child, the answer is quite obvious...

Comment: You tagged this with `jquery` *and* `css`. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You might find this useful: nth-child tester http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question *as written*, you'll need four styles, one for each animation duration:

```
.block:nth-child(4n) {
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.block:nth-child(4n+1) {
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

.block:nth-child(4n+2) {
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.block:nth-child(4n+3) {
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

The [`:nth-child` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) of `an + b` allows you to indicate your looping frequency with `a` and your initial offset with `b`. Each duration style needs its own `b` offset.

However, if you want to generalize this to *m* styles (instead of just 4), you should probably apply styles through a script, rather than writing them by hand.

Comment: Up voted! If OP is not using Sass or Less and wants easier updating this could be useful: `$('.block').css('animation-duration', function(i){ return ( i % 4 + 1 ) + 's'; });`

Answer (score 0):

If You are looking for jquery code then try this:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLJej/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#maindiv .block').each(function(){
duration=($(this).index()%4+1)*1000 ;
$(this).css('animation-duration',($(this).index()%4+1)+'s')
})
})
```